# Drupal nid and vid - Which is the final revision of the post

Tags: wordpress, drupal, migration

I am a WordPress developer trying to port a two year old Drupal installation to WordPress, I can't use most of the existing solutions because of the custom content type used in this installation.

I see a lot of nid's and vid's for the same post title - In the table called node, how do I know which is the final revision of the post  ?  Also, I have to import a lot of unpublished posts as well - that means, the Drupal installation has certain posts that are not yet published - how do I know which is the final revision of an unpublished post ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nid identifies the post as a whole, the vid can be seen as the version identifier.  The highest number vid for a given node will be the most recent revision.  The same concept applies to unpublished nodes.  Unpublished nodes are denoted with a `0` in the `status` column in the node table, while a `status` of `1` means a node *is* published.

Comment: Note that the highest vid for a certain nid is indeed the *most recent* revision, but not necessarily the *final* revision. A node may have been reverted to an earlier version. The `node` table has a `vid` column which stores the current vid for every nid.